# C# & ASP.NET Core MVC : web scraper ajax sends null to controller

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I'm trying to implement a simple screen scraper program in C#. When I run the application, and type in a url into the input box and click on the submit button, I execute some jQuery to use Ajax to send the url entered to the controller. For some reason, the controller is always receiving null.

This is the code in my view:

```
 <div id="message"></div>
 <input id="urlInput" type="text" placeholder="Enter URL" />
 <button id="submit">Submit</button> 
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
        var urlValue = $("#urlInput").val();
        console.log(urlValue);
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/GetUrlSource",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                data: '{"url":"' + urlValue + '"}',
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    ExtractData(result);
                    //GetUrlTelePhone(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    $("#message").html("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
                }
            });
    });
 </script>
```

When I run the application, the view is presented. In the input box, I type in the following:

```
https://www.zillow.com/homes/90-westwood-circle-roslyn-heights-ny-11577
```

When I click on the submit button, and I look at the browser console, I see the url so I know that the url value is valid when the `console.log` instruction executes.

This is the code in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public string GetUrlSource(string url)
{
    url = url.Substring(0, 4) != "http" ? "http://" + url : url;
    string htmlCode = "";

    using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            htmlCode = client.DownloadString(url);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    return htmlCode;
}
```

I have a breakpoint set at the first line of code in `GetUrlSource` and when I watch the variable url, it has a null value.

Any ideas why this is happening? I am running Visual Studio 2019 on a mac. The application is a .NET Core application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @zSynopsis `dataType` is the expected return type, not what's being sent, which is `contentType`

Comment: Try passing an object so jquery can convert it to json: `data: { url : urlValue },`

Comment: Look in the browser network tab to see how it's being sent.

Comment: @freedomn-m When I look at the network tab, I can see GetUrlSource in the Name column.  When I click on the Payload tab, I see the url that should be passed.

Comment: @freedomn-m I tried changing to an object as suggested but that still end up with null in the controller.

Comment: @Victor I tried.  Same results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 $("#submit").click(function (e) {
            var urlValue = $("#urlInput").val();
            console.log(urlValue);

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/Home/GetUrlSource",
                data: { url: urlValue },
                dataType: "html",
                success: function (result, status, xhr) {
                    ExtractData(result);
                    //GetUrlTelePhone(result);
                },
                error: function (xhr, status, error) {
                    $("#message").html("Result: " + status + " " + error + " " + xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText)
                }
            });
        });
```

There are two fixes in the code above:

1. `data: { url: urlValue },`
2. Removing `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` to use the default value. The default is: [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

This working for me. If will not work try to clean a browser cache.

[image]

Comment: Clearing the browser! Why didn't I think of that? Its always the simple things.  Thanks!

Comment: @JonathanSmall: This is not only clearing the browser cache. When I uncomment the  `contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',` line the `url` parameter of the `GetUrlSource(string url)` is always `null`.  Using _POST_ method affects how the contents of the `data` option are sent to the server and this why the `contentType` type become important.